# Display counter variable in my layout.app.blade in Laravel

Tags: laravel

i want to display the counter in my app.blade which being called in all pages like the screenshot below

[image]

I only have this function in my controller

```
class ReportsController extends Controller
{
    public function invoiceTransaction()
    {   
        $salespayments = Salespayments::where('type','=','check')->get();
        $countUnread = Salespayments::select(DB::raw("SUM(unread) as unread"))->get();
        

        return view('reports.invoiceTransactions')
                        ->with('salespayments', $salespayments)
                        ->with('countUnread', $countUnread);
    }
}
```

And I am calling the counter in my blade by this `{{$countUnread[0]->unread}}`

How can I make that function be readable in my app.blade.php? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `AppServiceProvider` you can share the `sum` result across all views by using `view()->share();`

Like this:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot() {
   $countUnread = Salespayments::sum('unread');
   view()->share('countUnread', $countUnread);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a service provider first,

```
php artisan make:provider CounterServiceProvider
```

Then in your `CounterServiceProvider` file.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Views\Composers;

class CounterServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // here define your master layout
        $this->app['view']->composer(['master'], Composers\Counter::class);
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Now in your `App\Views\Composers` folder add `Counter` class.

```
<?php
namespace App\Views\Composers;

use Illuminate\View\View;

class Counter {

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('countUnread', session('countUnread'));
    }
}
```

Make sure you add your `CounterServiceProvider` in config/app.php file's providers array.